# how to customize template in liferay theme

Tags: java, html, liferay, freemarker, portal

I'm customizing my liferay theme for my own portal, I'm copy `portal_normal.ftl` from classic theme to `_diffs/templates`  and I saw this code :

```
<a class="${logo_css_class}" href="${site_default_url}" title="<@liferay.language key="go-to" /> ${site_name}">
    <img alt="${logo_description}" height="${site_logo_height}" src="${site_logo}" width="${site_logo_width}" />
</a>
```

I want to change the src from `${site_logo}` to a direct url like `/images/blahblah.png` but it doesn't work, so how do i change the picture in this img tag ?

And where did the liferay define `${site_logo}` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find ${site_logo} in a file "init.ftl". This file is in:
liferay-portal-src-6.2.0-ce-ga1\portal-web\docroot\html\themes_unstyled\templates\init.ftl

To change the src, include in init_custom.ftl #set ($company_logo_src = "$images_folder/yourlogo.png"). Then in your portal_normal the tag img put src="$company_logo_src"

$images_folder is going to take the logo from folder images (of your theme). This var exist in init.ftl and have this value $theme_display.getPathThemeImages()

Comment: What about "${logo_css_class}" and "${site_default_url}" ? 
Do I define it the same way I define $company_logo_src ? Would you give me any tutorial to help me define these variables ?

Comment: you have all that in init.ftl. if you want to overwrite, the best is in your init_custom. This page can help you:http://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMS+Template+%28Velocity%29#section-CMS+Template+(Velocity)-Getting+data+out+of+different+types+of+fields